# Adding my flutter app to ultra power saving mode in android

Tags: android, flutter, power-saving

Is there a way I can allow my app to be added to the default ultra power saving mode in android? If not, can I get permission from the user? Adding REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS to my AndroidManifest file doesn't seem to work.